# insert trigger in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I cant find the right structure for the following question in pl/sql:
need a trigger on “products table” that will check the price before inserting a new product, product price must not exceed 4000$.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER pro 
BEFORE UPDATE OF price 
ON products
FOR EACH ROW 
declare 
pr products.price%type;
BEGIN 
if pr < 4000 then 
INSERT INTO products VALUES (:old.product_ID,:old.price);
end if; 
END;
```

Please help

Comment: Could you please add some details to what you are asking? It is not very clear right now...

Comment: Your code has a BEFORE UPDATE, but your question is about INSERT...?

Comment: yes its a before update but I need it to be insert which I couldnt do .. can yo please help in that?

Answer (score 4):

Use [check constraint](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php) instead of trigger:

```
create table products (price number);

ALTER TABLE PRODUCTS ADD CONSTRAINT check_price CHECK (price < 4000);
```

Test:

```
insert into products values (5000)  => ERROR
```

---

**Edit:** If you insist on trigger version:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER pro BEFORE insert or UPDATE OF price ON products 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
if :new.price > 4000 then 
  raise_application_error(-20101, 'Price exceeds 4000.');
end if; 
END;
```

Comment: I need it using a triggre function in PL/SQL

Comment: Thanks , just to make sure, you have used "insert or update of" the question i'm trying to solve is about insert only.. is this an accurate solution? I'm not sure as I'm new to pl/sql

Comment: But in your tries you wrote: _before update_ so I made version for insert and update - it seems most logical. Of course you can remove  `update of` part if you don't want it. But in current version it's universal.

Comment: I got this error
 ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword

Comment: why have you put this value -20101?

Comment: **1)** If you don't want `update` clause then first line should be `CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER pro BEFORE insert ON products`. **2)** As you can see in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i3329) valid error numbers for `raise_application_error` are in range -20000 .. -20999. You can put any number from this range which you want. **3)** Your questions are very basic, please read documentation of [triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm), especially examples.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason you would bother with a trigger for this instead of a check constraint is to control the error message. And remember that a trigger assumes that the operation is happening, so to stop the operation your tool is to raise an exception.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pro 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON products
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
if :new.price > 4000 then 
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Price exceeds maximum permitted value') ;
end if; 
END;
```

Comment: got this error" cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS"

Comment: why have you put this value -20001?

Comment: User-defined exceptions must follow the Oracle Error code + Message format, and Oracle reserves the range -20000 to -20999 for user-defined exceptions. All other error codes are theirs for internal use only

Answer (score 2):

if you don't like to raise errors and just keep old values as I think so, use this code:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER pro 
      BEFORE UPDATE OF price 
      ON products
      FOR EACH ROW 
declare 
   pr products.price%type;
BEGIN 
  if :new.price > 4000 then 
     :new.price := :old.price;
     :new.product_ID := :old.product_ID;
  end if; 
END;
```

Comment: got this error" cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS"

Comment: @Jaad can you please tell me what is the owner of products table?

Comment: I log in using sys/sys as sysdba

Comment: @Jaad Is your products table created in Sys schema? Can you log on with the Owner of products table?